# Prove any group with 3 elements is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Let $G = \left\{e, a, b \right\}$

Since $G$ has $3$ elements, $a \not= e , \,b \not= e, \,a \not= b$

$G$ is closed so $ab \in G$

If $ab = a$, this means that $b = e$
and if $ab = b$, $ a = e $

So we are left with $ab = e$

Define a function

$\varphi (a) = [1]$

$\varphi (b) = [2]$

To show that this function is an isomorphism,

$\varphi (e) = \varphi (ab) = \varphi (a) + \varphi (b) = [1] + [2] = [0]$

So $\varphi (e) = [0]$

So this function takes the identity to the identity, so it's an isomorphism.

Comment: Is this proof correct? Incomplete?

Comment: A bit of a mess, but mostly ok :-) In checking that the function is an isomorphism, you should really check all equations $\phi(x)\phi(y)=\phi(xy)$ with $x$ and $y$ running in $G$. You did not write that.

Comment: Whenever you define a function, be sure to be explicit about what its domain and its codomain are.

Comment: Using your method, we need to identify $aa$ and $bb$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Oh gosh I forgot about that. If $a^2 = e$ That means $a$ is it's own inverse- But I've shown that $b = a^{-1}$ So that's not possible. In the end $a^2$ must equal $b$.. This is too messy

Comment: Not really messy, multiplying the elements of $G$ by $a$ we must get $G$ back. Since $ae=a$ and $ab=e$ we must have $aa=b$, similarly $bb=b$. There are then two isomorphisms to $\mathbb{Z}_3$, pick one say $a$ goes to $1$ and $b$ to $2$. "Same" table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider $G=\{e,a,b\}$ where $e$ is the identity; then the Cayley table is at the beginning
$$
\begin{matrix}
e & a & b \\
a &  &  \\
b &  &
\end{matrix}
$$
In position $(2,2)$ we can have either $e$ or $b$. But if we have $e$, then position $(2,3)$ would have $b$, which is impossible. So we get
$$
\begin{matrix}
e & a & b \\
a & b & e \\
b &  &
\end{matrix}
$$
and now the table is easily completed:
$$
\begin{matrix}
e & a & b \\
a & b & e \\
b & e & a
\end{matrix}
$$
Thus $a^2=b$ and $a^3=ba=e$. Therefore $a$ is a generator of the group. So $G$ is cyclic of order $3$ and so isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$. You get an explicit isomorphism by comparing the Cayley tables.

---

In a more abstract way: consider the subgroup $H$ generated by $a$. Since $a\ne e$, we have $|H|>1$. By Lagrange's theorem $|H|$ divides $3$, so $|H|=3$ and therefore $G$ is cyclic with $a$ as a generator.

Consider the homomorphism $\varphi\colon\mathbb{Z}\to G$ defined by $\varphi(n)=a$. Then $\varphi$ is surjective and its kernel must be $3\mathbb{Z}$ because of the order. Thus $\varphi$ induces an isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} \to G$.

Answer (score 9):

More easier, let $G=\{e,a,b\}$.
$$ab=ba=e$$ and thus, it's commutative. Therefore it's a cyclic group with $3$ elements and thus, it's isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_3$.

Answer (score 1):

You have shown that $ab=e$. Now $a^2$ cannot equal $e$, because that would give an element of order two, forbidden because 2 does not divide 3. And $a^2$ cannot equal $a$, because then $a$ would equal $e$. So $a^2=b$, and thus $a^3=e$, so the group is cyclic.

Edit: Much simpler, since $a$ cannot be order two, it must be order three, and thus the group is cyclic.